# JavaScript stops prematurely

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, popup

thanks in advance for any help you are able to give.

I have been tasked with sorting out the company website. I have made my way through the majority of it however have become stuck on a piece of JavaScript.

The site has a questionnaire with answers in three categories. From the score I plot a triangle. I have written a function which will return the calculations I want. As a test of this function I can write the calculated variables directly to a popup window.

I have created another function to then draw the triangle using CANVAS() in a popup. As a test to see if the new function works I put in the code to try and create the popup with the results in it. It goes as far as creating the pop up but does not write to it, as if the code stops after creating the popup. Can anyone tell me what I have done wrong?

Regards
Drew

Code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

            function myFunction() 
            {                   
                function calcD() 
                {
                var D1 = parseInt(document.forms.form1.elements.RadioGroup1.value);
                var D2 = parseInt(document.forms.form1.elements.RadioGroup4.value);
                var D3 = parseInt(document.forms.form1.elements.RadioGroup7.value);
                var D4 = parseInt(document.forms.form1.elements.RadioGroup10.value);
                var Ds  = D1 + D2 + D3 + D4;
                return Ds;
                }

                function calcI() 
                {
                var I1 = parseInt(document.forms.form1.elements.RadioGroup2.value);
                var I2 = parseInt(document.forms.form1.elements.RadioGroup5.value);
                var I3 = parseInt(document.forms.form1.elements.RadioGroup8.value);
                var I4 = parseInt(document.forms.form1.elements.RadioGroup11.value);
                var Is  = I1 + I2 + I3 + I4;
                return Is;
                }

                function calcB() 
                {
                var B1 = parseInt(document.forms.form1.elements.RadioGroup3.value);
                var B2 = parseInt(document.forms.form1.elements.RadioGroup6.value);
                var B3 = parseInt(document.forms.form1.elements.RadioGroup9.value);
                var B4 = parseInt(document.forms.form1.elements.RadioGroup12.value);
                var Bs  = B1 + B2 + B3 + B4;
                return Bs;
                }

                var X = 396.4;
                var Y = 250;
                var coS30 = 0.866025403784439;
                var siN30m = -0.5;
                var siN30p = 0.5;
                var Dx = X;
                var Dy = calcD() + Y;
                var Bx = X - (calcB()*coS30);
                var By = Y + (calcB()*siN30m);
                var Ix = X + (calcI()*coS30);
                var Iy = Y + (calcI()*siN30p);
                var Xs = (Dx + Bx + Ix)/3;
                var Ys = (Dy + By + Iy)/3;
            /*
                var myWindow1 = window.open("","MsgWindow","resizable,height=700,width=793");

                myWindow1.document.write('var X = ' + X);
                myWindow1.document.write('; var Y = ' + Y);
                myWindow1.document.write('; var coS30 = ' + coS30);
                myWindow1.document.write('; var siN30m = ' + siN30m);
                myWindow1.document.write('; var siN30p = ' + siN30p);
                myWindow1.document.write('; var Dx = ' + Dx);
                myWindow1.document.write('; var Dy = ' + Dy);
                myWindow1.document.write('; var Bx = ' + Bx);
                myWindow1.document.write('; var By = ' + By);
                myWindow1.document.write('; var Ix = ' + Ix);
                myWindow1.document.write('; var Iy = ' + Iy);
                myWindow1.document.write('; var Xs = ' + Xs);
                myWindow1.document.write('; var Ys = ' + Ys);
                myWindow1.document.close();
            */
        }

    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

                function draw() {

                    var myWindow1 = window.open("","MsgWindow","resizable,height=700,width=793");

                    myWindow1.document.write('var X = ' + X);
                    myWindow1.document.write('; var Y = ' + Y);
                    myWindow1.document.write('; var coS30 = ' + coS30);
                    myWindow1.document.write('; var siN30m = ' + siN30m);
                    myWindow1.document.write('; var siN30p = ' + siN30p);
                    myWindow1.document.write('; var Dx = ' + Dx);
                    myWindow1.document.write('; var Dy = ' + Dy);
                    myWindow1.document.write('; var Bx = ' + Bx);
                    myWindow1.document.write('; var By = ' + By);
                    myWindow1.document.write('; var Ix = ' + Ix);
                    myWindow1.document.write('; var Iy = ' + Iy);
                    myWindow1.document.write('; var Xs = ' + Xs);
                    myWindow1.document.write('; var Ys = ' + Ys);
                    myWindow1.document.close();


            /*  
                var ctx = myWindow1.document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
                var img = new Image();

                img.onload = function() {
                ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.moveTo(Dx, Dy);
                ctx.lineTo(Bx, By);
                ctx.lineTo(Ix, Iy);
                ctx.fill();
                ctx.stroke();
                };
                img.src = "img/triangle.png";
            */
            };

    </script>
```

Variable values if you need them:

```
var X = 396.4; 

var Y = 250;
var coS30 = 0.866025403784439;
var siN30m = -0.5;
var siN30p = 0.5;
var Dx = 396.4;
var Dy = 250;
var Bx = 396.4;
var By = 250;
var Ix = 396.4;
var Iy = 250;
var Xs = 396.3999999999999;
var Ys = 250;
```

Comment: When you are writing that dynamic content into the new window (i.e. the vars) , should you not write a header , then script tag 1st and write it into there ? I think that you are just writing vars into the new DOM which will not be able to use them as not inside script tags ..

Comment: The problem may be your canvas. You are trying do draw a triangle from [396.4,
250] to  [396.4,250] to  [396.4,250]. It's always the same point

Comment: @mkane what is confusing me is that I can create the popup with the content from the first function, but in the second, it only creates the popup then stops. If I try to do everything from one function, everything fails

Comment: @enxaneta at the moment I have not used proper values as I am trying to trouble shoot why the function to draw the triangle won’t even write to the popup